# Replacing if-else within 'for' loops with Java-8 Streams

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I have following simple code that I am trying to convert to functional style

```
for(String str: list){
    if(someCondition(str)){
       list2.add(doSomeThing(str));
    }
    else{
        list2.add(doSomethingElse(str));
    }
}
```

Is it easily possible to replace this loop with stream? Only option I see is to iterate over the stream twice with two different filter conditions.

Comment: And why do you want to do that if your code just works?

Comment: Your could use a map with a conditional statement `List<String> list2 = list.stream().map(str -> someCondition(str) ? doSomeThing(str) : doSomethingElse(str)).collect(toList());`. Whether it is more readable or not is up to the reader (I find it clear personally). You can always extract this process into an helper method if you want.

Comment: @fge just to understand the functional programming better in Java :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It sounds like you can just use `map` with a condition:

```
List<String> list2 = list
    .stream()
    .map(str -> someCondition(str) ? doSomething(str) : doSomethingElse(str))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Short but complete example mapping short strings to lower case and long ones to upper case:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abC", "Long Mixed", "SHORT");
        List<String> list2 = list
            .stream()
            .map(str -> str.length() > 5 ? str.toUpperCase() : str.toLowerCase())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (String result : list2) {
            System.out.println(result); // abc, LONG MIXED, short
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since we're doing Java 8, we could also write the logging like this: list2.forEach(System.out::println);