# Java 8 sum or subtract depending on even odd

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have a list of int

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

How can do add if the number is even and subtract if the number is odd?
I can do this using a for loop but I want to know how I can do that using new Java 8 feature like `stream` and `filter`

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I have done it using for loop. I can do this using one condition but can get my head around about how to put 2 condition

Comment: seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609716/replacing-if-else-from-for-loops-with-streams

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible solution would be to map each value in the array to itself if it's even and to its opposite if it's odd. That way, by summing the result, you will have added all even numbers and subtracted all odd ones.

You can retrieve an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) from an int array with [`Arrays.stream(array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-), then use [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) to transform the even and odd values and finally call [`sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) to sum all values.

Sample code:

```
int[] array = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
int sum = Arrays.stream(array).map(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i : -i).sum();
```

Comment: thanks this is what i needed. could u do me one more favour. what if its a list of object. eg if list.getName == name1 then add if name2 then subtract

Comment: @Mahabub If it's a list of objects then please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31609716/1743880)