# Rewrite else-if within a single stream Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to write the following code using streams

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("pavan");
        l.add("kumar");
        l.add("rajesh");

        for(String s : l){
            if(s.contains("pavan")){
                methodA();
            }else if (s.contains("kumar")){
                methodB();
            }else{
                System.out.println("C");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following using streams

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("pavan");
        l.add("kumar");
        l.add("rajesh");
        l.stream().
        filter(s->s.contains("pavan")).
        findAny().map(s->methodB()).filter(s->s.contains("kumar")).map(s->methodC()).
        orElse(methodA());
    }
```

**The above code is never executing the `methodC()`**.

Can anyone rewrite it within a single Java 8 stream?

Comment: As soon as you called `filter(s->s.contains("pavan"))`, you only have results where value contains pavan in the stream. It's a totally different process... I don't see the point of trying to use stream here, it's not meant to replace if else statements.

Comment: I understood that .But how can i write code in lambda

Comment: If you really want to use streams.... 3 steps :

`l.stream().filter(s -> s.contains("pavan")).forEach(s -> methodA());` 

`l.stream().filter(s -> s.contains("kumar")).forEach(s -> methodB());`

`l.stream().filter(s -> !s.contains("pavan") && !s.contains("kumar")).forEach(s -> methodC());`

Comment: @MateoBarahona that's different, though: it executes all the `methodA()` calls, then all the `methodB()` calls etc; the original code code would interleave the calls, depending on the list's contents.

Comment: Yes, and since stream are not meant to replace `if/else`, basically you cannot do better than a `if/else` if you want to keep the order. You need to understand that. Then put your `if/else` in the stream if you just want to call `stream()`, but it's totally useless here.

Comment: If if it works, it's just horrible style to do so.

Comment: *I understood that .But how can i write code in lambda* you dont have to..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing if-else from for loops with streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609716/replacing-if-else-from-for-loops-with-streams)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use forEach:

```
l.stream().forEach(s -> {
        if (s.contains("pavan")) {
            methodA();
        } else if (s.contains("kumar")) {
            methodB();
        } else {
            methodC();
        }
    });
```